# Is it possible to Distinct Summary Count based on Multiple Criteria (IDs, Month & Name) in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Having Following Excel Table:

[image: Need to count Summary sells based on criteria (my inventory should be 0 and Name should be Distinct]

Based on image I have created an excel formula

`=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B9="Mar")*(E2:E9=0))`

and this give result 3 but correct result as per my requirement is 2 (don't want to count Apple 2 times in Mar month).

Comment: In your title you mentioned you want to count based on ID too. So why won't you want to count 'apples' in march two times when it's apparently sold to another ID?

Comment: That is for summary table to see if product are sold on same day (0) and if my ID series is same like 4.x.

Answer (score 2):

With Microsoft365 you could try:

[image]

Formula in `G2`:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(B2:B9,"Mar",E2:E9,0),COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(C2:C9,(E2:E9=0)*(B2:B9="Mar"),""))),0)
```

Answer (score 1):

In `G2`, enter formula :

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B9="Mar")*(E2:E9=0)/COUNTIFS(C2:C9,C2:C9,B2:B9,B2:B9,E2:E9,E2:E9))
```

[image]

Comment: You could also replace the sumproduct with counifs too?

Comment: short answer, "No" (Countifs cannot handle "divide").

Comment: I've just tried `=COUNTIFS($O$1:$O$9,"Mar",P1:P9,0)/COUNTIFS($N$1:$N$9,$N$1:$N$9,$O$1:$O$9,$O$1:$O$9,$P$1:$P$9,$P$1:$P$9)`  as an array formula and it worked?  Assuming OP just needs this as a formula and the VBA tag is incorrect :)

Comment: You one is a different formula, Sumproduct+Countifs is a non-array formula.

Comment: Post your formula as a option. But I check your formula return 3, and not 2 as per the OP mentioned.